# Good study material for WPF Styles

Tags: wpf

Can anybody tell me some tutorials or study materials for learning WPF styles for button,labels and for other wpf controls.

I Searched on google but no proper material i found for a beginner like me.

Comment: @DanPuzey might be i have not search well as i am new to this technology so i dont know the keywords ...and by the way ur link is saying that Article not found!

Comment: Apologies, the link I posted wasn't formatted well: it's the same page that DorCohen has posted: http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

Answer (score 3):

Start in the [MSDN: Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773)

You can use Blend to copy the existing style/template and examine those. If Blend is not available you could serialize the Templates and styles yourself using the Xaml Serializer.

Answer (score 2):

http://wpftutorial.net/ is a great website..

look at http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not the exact answer to your question but if you really want to get deeper in WPF technology I sincerely recommend the best book about WPF (which also covers the idea of styles): 
[WPF Unleashed](http://www.amazon.co.uk/WPF-4-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672331195/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1344238759&sr=8-1)