# Group Styling XAML elements in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create a WPF software with XAML and C#. The software uses lots of TextBoxs and Labels that have similar looks/styles.

For example in the following code all my labels share the same HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, Margin, and FontSize. How can I assign a class or common style to apply to all of the elements? In other words, I'm looking for something similar to Classes and IDs in CSS.

```
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Content="Project Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="ProjectNameInput" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="5,1"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Content="Activity Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="ActivityNameInput" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="5,1"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Content="Address:" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="AddressInput" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="5,1"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Content="Latitude:" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="LatitudeInput" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="5,1"/>
```

Comment: Search "WPF Styles" on your favourite search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about Styles in WPF. Google "wpf styles", an example of one good tutorial is http://www.wpftutorial.net/styles.html.

Another good question from StackOverflow is [Good study material for WPF Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823978/good-study-material-for-wpf-styles).